# Can I remove the Clonezilla USB media while it is running?

Tags: usb-drive, live-usb, clonezilla

I booted the [Clonezilla live image](http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=stable) from a USB stick and am currently in the proces of cloning my internal HDD from it.

If this was a normal Debian live USB, taking out the USB stick during operation would cause the system to crash.

But I think perhaps the Clonezilla live  system runs entirely from RAM? So, could I just withdraw it from the USB port, while the program is running? It would make sense if they designed it like that, as some people have a limited number of USB ports and may need them for the devices they are cloning from or to.

I am asking because the cloning is taking a while and I want to use the USB stick for something else while I wait.

I have tried searching the internet for this, but I could not find an answer. Also, I do not want to just try as an experiment, as I do not want to risk having to restart the cloning and/or corrupting any of the media involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the clonezilla usb drive only if you selected `Clonezilla live (To RAM. Boot media can be removed later)` in the boot menu under `Other modes of Clonezilla live`.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the options that allow to remove the Clonezilla USB and swap it for the backup media are those that include "to RAM" in their tittle. There are several.